Why is the state not updating in one case but do so in the other?
I've stumbled across a little mystery for which I'd be happy to get an explanation.
Take a component that need one of its state to update when one of its prop change. One possibility is to use the pattern of storing the value of the prop in a state, and then compare this value with the prop to detect when it changed, so no useEffect is required. Now, I thought it should also work if instead of storing the prop in a state, I was storing it in a ref. Except that it doesn't.
This will correctly update the state:
const MyComponent = ({ value }) => {
  const [prevValue, setPrevValue] = useState(value);
  const [otherState, setOtherState] = useState(true);

  if(value !== prevValue) {
    setPrevValue(value);
    setOtherState(prev => !prev);
  }

  ...
}

But this will not:
const MyComponent = ({ value }) => {
  const valueRef = useRef(value);
  const [otherState, setOtherState] = useState(true);

  if(value !== valueRef.current) {
    valueRef.current = value;
    setOtherState(prev => !prev);
  }

  ...
}

In both cases, it goes into the if each time value changes, so in both cases the change is correctly detected. But when using the ref, otherState is simply not updated.
Here is a sandbox showing this. When clicking on the "Update" button, we can see on the state example (left) that the text correctly switch from "Loading..." to "Loaded!", while on the ref example (right), it never changes.
Why is the behavior different?

The docs state: Do not write or read ref.current during rendering, except for initialization. This makes your component’s behavior unpredictable.

@kzi Good finding, I guess this could be the answer

sandbox is not working

@TusharShahi You're right, I forgot to make it public, link fixed

We have already established that you React code is impure. You are directly updating ref inside you render body. And React recommends against it. To help figure out such instances, React has StrictMode, which will often help you identify bugs like these only in development mode.
If you do not wrap your code in <StrictMode>, then you can see the expected behaviour.
React does double rendering during strict mode.
Had you not used StrictMode you would not have found the bug (updating ref directly). So <StrictMode> fulfills its purpose.

From the docs:

If you have React DevTools installed, any console.log calls during the second render call will appear slightly dimmed. React DevTools also offers a setting (off by default) to suppress them completely.

Using the console you can check that, the console.log inside first if condition runs twice and the one inside second if condition only runs once. Here is how:
I am using one component at a time, so logs are easy to understand.
When React does double rendering it is almost like a clean slate for the component. States get reset, effects are run again.
Notice the logs from console.js file instead of App.js. They are caused by the intentional rerender.

For state mode:
In the second intentional render, the value of state is reset to the previous value. The if condition code runs again, which sets isLoading to true.
For ref mode:
The ref value is does not reset, when double render happens. React preserves the ref value from previous render. There is no log in console.js file from inside the if condition. All the logs from console.js show the value of isLoading to false. The value of src ref is always the new one.


To summarise
React does not reset the value of ref variable during Strict Mode intentional re-render but resets the value of state variable.
PS: Some of the above was experimentation, and I do not have docs for it. But, I think it is correct. All the logs from console.js disappear when you remove StrictMode.

I don't really understand your explanations about the logs, but the first part of the answer is enough for me, thank you.

Ok. I have tried to update the answer. Please let me know which part is not clear. I want this answer to be useful
